# Multi audio tracks for html5 video mp4

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have been building a simple html5 and javascript application for a video player where multiple audio tracks are available and I can select a specific track. But there no solutions for a mp4 file as it takes m3u8 format but i need a simple mp4 solution . I dont how to do that ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a question? Maybe your code might help?

Comment: Share your code, we can help

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to play `mp4` files.

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="YOURFILE" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and following code for `m3u8` file.

```
<video width="600" height="400" controls>
    <source src="YOURFILE" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Replace `YOURFILE` with your file or file link.